# XMPP with a Google Cloud Printer registered with a different client id and secret

Tags: google-cloud-print

My company was using a third party tool to download print jobs from Google. This has developed problems so we've written our own. We can register a printer, get notifications via XMPP and download jobs. All good. We'd like to download jobs from the printers already registered via the the third party tool.

We have successfully got the permission of the google account that owns the printer to manage its printers and subsequently downloaded jobs from the printer. This was achieved using a solution that issued /fetch api calls every minute. Of course, Google wants the XMPP method used so we tried to do that. After getting over an authentication issue by adding googletalk to the scope in the oAuth request we fail to get any notifications.

In summary, with our own printer we can fetch, download and get XMPP notifications but with the printer registered with the third party tool (where we don't know the client id and secret but do know the google account) we can fetch and download but not get XMPP notifications. Is there any way round this?

Answer (score 1):

The XMPP messages go to the robot account that owns the printer, so I don't think you should expect to receive XMPP messages without that robot account (and corresponding XMPP JID).

Rather than work around the intentions of the API, I suggest you work with the third party. Maybe they can provide hooks into their notification queue?

Comment: Well, I didn't expect to be able to download print jobs. Why allow that and not enable notifications?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I don't know why.